# What is tail -n0 -f vs tail -n1 -f

Tags: linux, bash, shell, tail

I have wrote a simple script to keep monitor log file and append line and have implement some if statement if memet.

From my understanding, `tail -n0 -f` and `tail -n1 -f` both will does the job where you tell your script to keep monitor this log file of last line at the time and append one at the time.

Key thing is last line.

Comment: Also take a look at the documentation: `man tail`

Answer (score 1):

`tail -n0 -f` print NO lines, then waits for incoming new lines.

`tail -n1 -f` print the last line of the input file, then waits for new lines.

If no `-n` is provided, it defaults to `10`.

Comment: Sorry a little confuse, So if my script has a simple while loop and pipe to this tail -n0 -f vs pipe to tail -n1 -f. And keep monitor /var/log and if a string detected, echo it out and exit . Restart this process over and over. From my testing, it is both doing the same in tern of result. no ?

Comment: So yeah so what is the real differences ? like so if I have it tail -n0 -f | while read lines ; do ..... done ; it will keep follow the last line of the log file I want to monitor and only that last line. So if any new line not line(s) get added, it will run what is in my while loop.

Comment: ```#!/bin/bash

tail -n0 -f  /var/log/auth.log | while read lines; do
        if [[ $lines =~ "password changed for root" ]] 
        then
                echo "found"
                break
                #pkill -9 -P $$ tail
        fi 
done 
echo "exit " 
#kill $(jobs -p)
exit 0```

Comment: create a static file, put 5-10 lines in the file with the last line including the string `password changed for root`; in your script replace `/var/log/auth.log` with the static file; now run your script a few times with `tail -n1` and then `tail -n0`; you script should repeatedly report 'found' when using `tail -n1`

Comment: your current script may appear to behave the same for `tail -n0` and `tail -n1` but that's probably because new lines are constantly being added to `/var/log/auth.log`; net result is in your analysis you also have to take into account new lines being added to `/var/log/auth.log` while you're running your script; my previous comment - use a static file - should show that `tail -n0` and `tail -n1` do not behave the same (when the string you're looking for exists in the last line of the static file)